# float a list-group to the right

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I am new to Bootstrap and have 15 list items. I want that the last 7 items are on the right (see picture of current situation). I have tried several tutorials but it doesn't work. Can you guys help me and give me some approach on how to do it?

I would appreciate your help even this is a total beginner question.

I want to do it like this:

[image: like this]

[image: list-item]

```
<section class="info2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="section-heading">Der einfache uns sichere Weg</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS-Grid can do that.

We just provide 2 "columns" and set the number of rows to "8" (in this case as 15 -7 = 8)

```css
.list-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow:column;
}
```

```html
<section class="info2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="section-heading">Der einfache uns sichere Weg</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Alternatively**

If the number of `li` is **unknown** and the last 7 items need to be in the second column, this is also possible with `:nth-last-child(-n+7)`

```css
.list-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

li {
  grid-column: 1;
}

li:nth-last-child(-n+7) {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<section class="info2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="section-heading">Der einfache uns sichere Weg</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
      <li>Item 9</li>
      <li>Item 10</li>
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
      <li>Item 13</li>
      <li>Item 14</li>
      <li>Item 15</li>
      <li>Item 16</li>
      <li>Item 17</li>
      <li>Item 18</li>
      <li>Item 19</li>
      <li>Item 20</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you very much it helped!

I have an additional question: when I shrank the size down (for example for mobile phone screen size), is it possible that it shows it again like one column? Now when I shrank the size down in mobile screen size then it shows two colums instead of one. Is this possible?

Comment: You just need to remove the `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);` in your mobile media query.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean? I just removed it but when it is on mobile screen size it still shows the content in two columns. Sry I am a beginner. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try removing the `li:nth-last-child(-n+7)` rule also. Otherwise, create a NEW question with the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.list-group {
  display:grid !important;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(2,1fr);
}

li:nth-child(1) {
grid-column:1/3 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="info2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="section-heading">Der einfache uns sichere Weg</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I mean that the last 7 items are on the same line and not like you did it. Can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: it should be like this:

abc          abc
___________

abc          abc
___________

abc           abc
____________

Comment: It wasn't what I mean. Please see my edit what I mean

Comment: wow that's what I was looking for! But why is it not beginning from the first item. It seems like it starts make in inline from the second item on. Can you explain me your css code? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Behar I deleted it. It was unnecessary. Please accept the my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

dont know if this is what you wanted, have a look ?

```css
.list-group{
display: block !important;
min-width: calc((1000px / 7) * 7);
overflow:auto;
}

li:nth-last-child(-n+7) {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% / 7);
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="info2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="section-heading">Der einfache uns sichere Weg</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```